# Make pictures on my website slide from right to left during its timed transition

Tags: javascript, html, image, animation, slideshow

I am trying to make the pictures on my website slide from right to left in a timed transition. So far I have it transition at certain time but the next picture does not slide from right to left. I added my header and updated code. I am now having an issue where the pictures are covering the header and don't slide over top each other.

```
HTML
<style>
.Header {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height:70px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align:right;
        }
        .socialmedia {
            position:fixed;
            right:100px;
            top:35px;
            transform:translate(0,-50%);
            display: flex; /* add this */
            align-items: center; /* add this */
        }
        .preorder button {
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            height: 35px;
            width: 110px;
            margin-left: 35px;
        }
.photoSection{
            direction:rtl
        }
        .mySlides {
            position: relative;

            right: -1000px;
            -webkit-animation: slide 1s forwards;

            animation: slide 1s forwards;

        }

        @-webkit-keyframes slide {
            100% { right: 0; }
        }

        @keyframes slide {
            100% { right: 0; }
        }
</style>
<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;">Some Title</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>

    </a>
    <div class="socialmedia">
        <a class = "Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = preorder>
            <button style = "background-color: white;">Pre-Order</button>

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="photoSection">
    <img src="board.png" style="width: 100%; height: 785px">
    <img src = "pic2.png" style = "width: 100%; height: 786px">
    <img src = "pic3.png" style = "width: 100%; height: 786px">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
</div>

JavaScript
<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 2500);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to achieve the right to left transition
you can find it here

HTML

```
<div class="photoSection">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=board&h=786&w=786" class="mySlides" style="width: 100%; height: 785px">
    <img src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic1&h=786&w=786"  class="mySlides" style = "width: 100%; height: 786px">
    <img src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=pic2&h=786&w=786"  class="mySlides" style = "width: 100%; height: 786px">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photoSection{
  direction:rtl
}
.mySlides {
  position: absolute;

    right: -1000px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 1s forwards;

    animation: slide 1s forwards;

}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { right: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { right: 0; }
}
```

JS

```
  var myIndex = 0;


    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        console.log(x);
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
    }

        carousel();
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/wy4gLa3n/1/

Comment: So this works but some of the issues that I am having are, the pictures overlay the header it needs to be just below the header. (I am about to add the header to my code). The other thing is that as the pictures scroll, I see a scrollbar on the bottom of the website, I don't want that. The other thing that I forgot to mention is that I need the picture to animate over top the current picture, so that the current picture disappears once the other picture is on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

So I use a carousel on my html. Heres your answer:

```
HTML
<div class="slider">
<img id="1" src="board.png">
<img id="2" src = "pic2.png">
<img id="3" src = "pic3.png">
</div>

JavaScript
$(document).ready(function(){
slider();
});
function slider() {
$(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
$(".slider #1").delay(2000).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

var sc=$(".slider img").size();
var count= 2;



setInterval(function(){

$(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);

$(".slider #"+count).delay(2000).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);


if(count == sc)

 {count = 1;}

else

 {

count=count+1;

}


},3000);

}



CSS

.slider {width: 550px; height:270px;

overflow:hidden; margin:30px auto;

}

.slider img {

width: 550px; height:270px; display:none;

border="0"

}
```

Heres a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/88u56y9h/1/